# need to close in app browser and open system browser

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var qq, winloc, standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
        userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        safari = /safari/.test(userAgent),
        ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test(userAgent);
ios ? !standalone && safari || standalone || safari || (qq = window.location.href, window.close(), window.open(qq, "_system", "location=yes", replace)) : userAgent.includes("wv") && (qq = window.location.href, window.close(), winloc = "intent:" + qq + "#Intent;end", window.location = winloc); 
</script>
```

This code makes the visitor, when he visits the site through the TikTok application, open for him in app browser When entering the TikTok browser, the TikTok browser is closed and the system browser is opened
but didn't work with me there is any suggest ?

Comment: Could you format your code, please?

Comment: "but didn't work with me" — Are you saying that there is a problem with something (unspecified) about your system that prevents that code from working? Or are you saying that you found some code that someone else wrote and it doesn't do what they claim it should do?

Comment: yes i found this code and its working with someother but not working with me

Comment: are you working with android app or ios app or any other js framework?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system');` to open it in system browser??

Comment: One general piece of advise. Do not simply copy code from the internet. Try to understand it, then adjust it accordingly for your scenario (if needed). See it like a source for inspiration. From the way your question/comments are worded, I feel like you're simply copy/pasting code without fully understanding it.

Comment: `replace` option is deprecated in `window.open( )` and do you have any idea what any of this code actually does?

Comment: Check this link (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for `window.open()` and `window.close()` methods to open and close browser window. Check this link (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/user-agent/) for understanding of *user-agent* strings.

Comment: not working with me give action not completed on tiktok

Comment: Go read the given links and after you have some understanding of what the code does, please come back and update your question.

Comment: Also, what does "didn't work for me" mean? Atleast tell us which device were you using and what actually happened?

Comment: What devices will you be targeting with this app? ex: android, ios, windows, macOs,etc.